# Unable to handle crystal report exception from .NET framework's exceptional handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, appdynamics

I am .net developer and using SAP crystal report.Unable to handle crystal report exception from .NET framework's exceptional handler.When using CrystalReportViewer to view report i am not getting any issue and try catch of .net framework also not catching any exception but third party tool APPD is capturing exception when previewing all crystal report.I can't predict the root cause as well as unable to get definition from forums.The exception getting in APPD is,

> Name: ArgumentOutofRangeException Summary:
>   CrystalDecisions.Shared.Json.JsonObject::unable to get optional
>   boolean value associated with key, at
>   CrystalDecisions.Shared.Json.JsonObject.get_Item(String key)

Thanks in Advance :-)

Comment: you need to provide your actual code example where exception is raised. it will help us to understand your scenario. Thanks

Comment: Actually this kind of exception occurring on all crystal reports.This exception not capturing in error log and there is no issue from UI side also but exception showing only in AppDynamics tool.

Comment: check my answer and the given reference, it will help you to understand the exception. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

An ArgumentOutOfRangeException exception is thrown when a method is invoked and at least one of the arguments passed to the method is not null and contains an invalid value that is not a member of the set of values expected for the argument. The ParamName property identifies the invalid argument, and the ActualValue property, if a value is present, identifies the invalid value.

Typically, an ArgumentOutOfRangeException results from developer error. Instead of handling the exception in a try/catch block, you should eliminate the cause of the exception or, if the argument is returned by a method call or input by the user before being passed to the method that throws the exception, you should validate arguments before passing them to the method.

**Reference:**  [ArgumentOutofRangeException Summary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentoutofrangeexception(v=vs.110).aspx)

Hope It Help you to understand the exception.